# Getting Current Date and time without using Internet Services or RTC

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, date-time

I have a MT7681 module with limited interfaces. One of the interface is Wi-Fi.
I have been using Wi-Fi interface(NTP) to get current Date and time. So, in one of the use case Internet services are not accessible from the module. Is it possible to get current date Time information without Internet over Wi-Fi.

Thanks

Apurv

Comment: It is possible to run a local NTP server on Linux. In this scenario, the server provides the necessary information (the server itself does not necessarily need internet access).

Comment: I don't have any Linux based system in my set-up. All i have is router and my device.

Comment: I see. Just as a comment, I think it's going to be hard to find a good alternative solution that doesn't involve running an NTP service yourself (either on a compatible router with a hardware clock and custom firmware with an NTP service e.g OpenWRT or running a server on the network). As an FYI, I don't know what your project requirements are, but a Raspberry Pi could make a good NTP server for this purpose consider that it is also a relatively cheap "project board" computer.